# Passing Parameters to a Mail Script

Tags: python

I want to send an email from python using the below codes i wrote/reffered

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#form1").submit(function(){
        $("#form1").validationEngine();
        if($('div input[type=text]').val() != "")
    {
        var textfield2=document.getElementById("textfield2").value;
        var textarea=document.getElementById("textarea").value;
        var dataS=$("#form1").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: 'true',
            url: "mail.py",
            success: function( ){
                alert("completed");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert(dataS);
            }

        });
    }
    return false;  

    }); 

});
</script>
```

For the mail part , i reffered the below google code

```
from google.appengine.api import mail

mail.send_mail(sender="Example.com Support <support@example.com>",
              to="Albert Johnson <Albert.Johnson@example.com>",
              subject="Your account has been approved",
              body="""
Dear Albert:

Your example.com account has been approved.  You can now visit
http://www.example.com/ and sign in using your Google Account to
access new features.

Please let us know if you have any questions.

The example.com Team
""")
```

Now the question is , on ajax call .. How can i recieve the HTML parameters in the mail.py script? pls help i'm new to python

Answer (score 0):

Within a cgi script, if you instantiate a [`cgi.FieldStorage()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi#using-the-cgi-module), it is automatically filled with the GET or POST parameters. If you want to post content, then just add a [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) property to your ajax request object:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {param1: 'value1', param1: 'value2', ...}
    ...
})
```

In your python script it should the be enough to do:

```
import cgi
store = cgi.FieldStorage()
par1 = store.getfirst('param1')
...
```

One more thing -
Ask yourself: do you really want to submit the form when the page is loaded? (Your're using the 'ready' event). Wouldn't it be better to wait until somebody has entered somehting in the form?